# Google Script UrlFetchApp.fetch() does not retrieve the entire HTML

Tags: fetch, screen-scraping

I would like to extract the price of a product from this page link :
https://gourmetmarketthailand.com/en/ritter_sport_almond_chocolate_100g_55161315168523

I am using UrlFetchApp.fetch() from Google Sheet script function but the function does not retrieve the whole HTML.

It seems that the website is constructed to avoid data scraping.

Anyone can help ?